# Outer apply with INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I want to do something like this

```
CREATE TABLE #tempFacilitiesAssociated 
(
     FacilityID BIGINT, 
     FacilityName VARCHAR(MAX), 
     IsPrimary BIT
)

-- Insert statements for procedure here
;WITH CTE_RESULT AS 
(
    SELECT
        usr_id, t.name AS Title, 
        usr_fname, usr_lname, primaryAddress.add_suburb,
        CASE
           WHEN primaryAddress.add_suburb = @suburb THEN 1
           WHEN t.name = @Title THEN 2
           ELSE 3
        END AS MatchOrder
    FROM
        core_users u
    LEFT JOIN
        RIDE_ct_title t ON t.title_id = u.usr_title
    OUTER APPLY
        (INSERT INTO #tempFacilitiesAssociated 
             EXEC dbo.[sp_Common_Get_AllFacilitiesForSupervisor] usr_id, 5

         SELECT TOP 1 fa.* 
         FROM CORE_Facilities f 
         LEFT JOIN CORE_FacilityAddresses fa ON fac_id = fa.add_owner
         WHERE fac_id = (SELECT TOP 1 FacilityID 
                         FROM #tempFacilitiesAssociated 
                         WHERE IsPrimary = 1)) primaryAddress
    WHERE
        u.usr_fname = @FirstName AND usr_lname = @LastName
)
```

So, first I want to get all facilities of that user through a stored procedure, and then use it to outer apply and select its suburb

**UPDATE**

I tried using function instead

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_GetAddressForUserFacility
    (@UserID BIGINT)
RETURNS @Address TABLE (FacilityID BIGINT, 
                        add_address NVARCHAR(MAX), 
                        add_addressline2 NVARCHAR(MAX), 
                        add_suburb NVARCHAR(MAX) 
                       )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FacilitiesAssociated TABLE
                                  (FacilityID BIGINT, 
                                   FacilityName NVARCHAR(MAX), 
                                   IsPrimary BIT)

    INSERT INTO @FacilitiesAssociated 
        EXEC dbo.[sp_Common_Get_AllFacilitiesForSupervisor] @UserID, 5

    INSERT INTO @Address
        SELECT TOP 1 
            fa.add_owner, fa.add_address, fa.add_addressline2, fa.add_suburb 
        FROM 
            CORE_Facilities f 
        LEFT JOIN 
            CORE_FacilityAddresses fa ON f.fac_id = fa.add_owner AND add_type = 5
        WHERE
            fac_id = (SELECT TOP 1 FacilityID 
                      FROM @FacilitiesAssociated 
                      WHERE IsPrimary = 1)  
    RETURN 
END
```

But now its returning

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  If SQL Server, this syntax is not allowed.

Comment: In this case, you'll probably have to find out what that stored procedure does, and work the same logic into the query.

Comment: the quick answer I can think of is get a unique list of usr_id then loop through using a cursor or another matter and insert the results of stored proc into temp table.  After that just join it into your query the way you want.

Comment: I actually ended up replicating the sp logic in my function